# node.js email verification token

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to set up a verification step in Mongoose, Express Node application based on this blog post ... http://danielstudds.com/adding-verify-urls-to-an-express-js-app-to-confirm-user-emails-secure-spa-part-6/ that post is over a year old so it kind of surprises me that its the first google result for 'node email verification'. I'm very new to node so I'm reliant on examples. Based on that post I did not see a download so I pieced it together to suit my scenario and here is what my code looks like.

**Verification Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    User = require('mongoose').model('User');

var verificationTokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _userid : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   token: {type: String, required: true},
   createdAt: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: '4h'}
});

verificationTokenSchema.methods = {
   createVerificationToken : function (done) {

      var verificationToken = this;
      var token = uuid.v4();
      verificationToken.set('token', token);
      verificationToken.save( function (err) {
         if (err) return done(err);
            return done(null, token);
      });
   }
};

exports.verifyUser = function(token, done) {
   verificationTokenModel.findOne({token: token}, function (err, doc){
      if (err) return done(err);
      User.findOne({_id: doc._userId}, function (err, user) {
         if (err) return done(err);
         user["verified"] = true;
         user.save(function(err) {
            done(err);
         });
      });
   });
};


var verificationTokenModel = mongoose.model('VerificationToken', verificationTokenSchema);
exports.verificationTokenModel = verificationTokenModel;
```

Then in my User model I call create like so..

**User Model**

```
exports.createUser = function(req, res, next) {
   // Do all the stuff that creates the user save it and get the id back
   var verificationToken = new verificationTokenModel({_userId: user._id});
   verificationToken.createVerificationToken(function (err, token) {
       if (err){
           err = new Error("Couldn't create verification token");
           res.status(400);
           return res.send({reason:err.toString()});
        }

        // Do stuff with the token here and email
```

This works 'partially' in my db 'verificationtokens' collection the objects don't contain a _userid they contain the _userid (user._id) stored in _id

My first issue is I don't really understand how this works when there isn't a 'constructor'

```
var verificationToken = new verificationTokenModel({_userId: user._id});
```

and how do I get this to store the user._id as _userid in the verification collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Mongoose, but here is what it happened:

- For your first question:

when you run:

```
var verificationTokenModel = mongoose.model('VerificationToken', verificationTokenSchema);
```

it creates the constructor.

- For the second question:

MongoDB always create documents with a field called "_id", so, the "_id" field in your verification collection is not the "_id" field from your User collection. The reason that _userid is not inserted is because you have a typo:

```
var verificationToken = new verificationTokenModel({_userId: user._id});
```

where "_userId" should be "userid"

Comment: Dang it - can't believe I missed that. So a follow up question now that its working correctly - in the verificationtokens collection the _userid and the _id now match so for example they both have a value of ObjectId("12345") why is that?